# Modify SVG path

Tags: svg, svg-path

I've been trying for a few hours to edit my SVG by editing a path element but I can't get the result I want:

The code looks like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="circle style-scope iron-icon" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 24px; height: 24px;">
    <g class=" style-scope iron-icon">
      <path d="M12 7c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5s2.24 5 5 5 5-2.24 5-5-2.24-5-5-5zm0-5C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z" class="style-scope iron-icon">
      </path> 
    </g>
  </svg>
```

And the rendered graphic looks like this:

[image: SVG output]

What I want to do is edit the inner black circle; I need to remove the right half of the circle.

I searched for sites which explain how to do it but I didn't found anything helpful.

Is it possible to paste the code in an SVG editor, and then edit the image and get the code back?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner circle is drawn with four cubic Bezier curve commands. Simply remove the two commands drawing the right side of the inner circle.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="circle style-scope iron-icon" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 24px; height: 24px;">
    <g class=" style-scope iron-icon">
      <path d="M12 7 c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5 s2.24 5 5 5zm0-5C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z" class="style-scope iron-icon">
      </path> 
    </g>
</svg>
```

A description of the cubic Bezier curve commands can be found at:
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands